# Can't access a property in a Struct

Tags: ios, swift

I have the struct `Subsection`, like so:

```
struct Subsection: Decodable {
    let subsectionName: String
    let subsectionID: Int
}
```

That is a type in another class `MenuInfo`, like so:

```
struct MenuInfo: Decodable {
    let subsections: [Subsection]
    let menuItems: [MenuItem]
}
```

Which finally is used inside another struct `RestaurantInfo`, like so:

```
struct RestaurantInfo: Decodable {
    let restaurantName: String
    let menuInfo: MenuInfo
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case restaurantName = "restaurant_name"
        case menuInfo
    }
}
```

I created a mock constant:

```
let restaurantMenuInfo = RestaurantInfo(
    restaurantName: "SUBWAY",
    menuInfo: MenuInfo(
        subsections: [
            Subsection(subsectionName: "SANDWICHES", subsectionID: 1),
            Subsection(subsectionName: "DRINKS", subsectionID: 2),
            Subsection(subsectionName: "DESSERTS", subsectionID: 3)
        ],
        menuItems: [
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Chicken Sandwich", menuItemDescription: "Bread / Chicken Filé / Cheese", menuItemPrice: 9.99, subsection: 1),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "BLT", menuItemDescription: "Bread / Bacon / Lettuce / Tomatoes", menuItemPrice: 12.99, subsection: 1),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "BBQ sandwich", menuItemDescription: "Garlix Bread / BBQ Sauce / Roast Beef", menuItemPrice: 14.99, subsection: 1),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Veggie Burger", menuItemDescription: "Bread / Soy Meat / Pickles", menuItemPrice: 17.99, subsection: 1),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Mountain Dew", menuItemDescription: "Lemon / Raspberry / Grape", menuItemPrice: 2.99, subsection: 2),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Iced Tea", menuItemDescription: "Tea with Lemon", menuItemPrice: 3.99, subsection: 2),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Cookie", menuItemDescription: "Chocolate Chip Cookie", menuItemPrice: 1.99, subsection: 3),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Cheese Cake", menuItemDescription: "Cheese cake / Blueberry", menuItemPrice: 5.99, subsection: 3),
            MenuItem(menuItemName: "Chips", menuItemDescription: "Potato chips", menuItemPrice: 2.99, subsection: 3)
        ]
    )
)
```

I am trying to get a stack view to load a `.xib` final with the `subsectionName` but I can't access the property `subsectionName` in the `ViewController`.

```
func setUpMenuSubsection() {
    for subsection in restaurantMenuInfo.menuInfo.subsections.subsectionName {
        if let subsectionView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SubsectionView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? SubsectionView {
            subsectionView.setUpSubsection(subsection: subsection)

            stackSubsections.addArrangedSubview(subsectionView)
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Value of type '[Subsection]' has no member 'subsectionName' on the second line of my function right on ".subsectionName".

Comment: `subsections` is an array (as it says, `[Subsection]`).  You need to choose a specific element before you can get its name.

Comment: Drop the `.subsectionName` from the line that gives the error (and perhaps add it somewhere else but I can't tell from your code where you would need that property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup of your types is perfectly fine. However, when we look at the loop you are using:

```swift
func setUpMenuSubsection() {
    for subsection in restaurantMenuInfo.menuInfo.subsections.subsectionName { // <-- this line
        if let subsectionView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SubsectionView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? SubsectionView {
            subsectionView.setUpSubsection(subsection: subsection)

            stackSubsections.addArrangedSubview(subsectionView)
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on the marked line. That is because `subsections`, which is of type `[Subsection]`, does not have a property `subsectionName`. If you just want to loop over the subsections (which is probably what you want), you can simply remove `.subsectionName`, and then to access the name of each subsection, inside the loop you would say `subsection.subsectionName` like so:

```swift
func setUpMenuSubsection() {
    for subsection in restaurantMenuInfo.menuInfo.subsections {
        print(subsection.subsectionName)
    }
}
```

If, however, you want to loop only over the names, and do not care about the subsections themselves, you can do this:

```swift
func setUpMenuSubsection() {
    for subsectionName in restaurantMenuInfo.menuInfo.subsections.map(\.subsectionName) {
        print(subsectionName)
    }
}
```